# Unable to find source package for linux-image-5.13.0-30-generic

Tags: package-management, kernel

I tried to install kernel for the first time by using [BuildYourOwnKernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel) Guide.
To download some packages I have run this command:

`sudo apt-get build-dep linux linux-image-$(uname -r)`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Picking 'linux-signed-hwe-5.13' as source package instead of 'linux-image-5.13.0-30-generic'
E: Unable to find a source package for linux-image-5.13.0-30-generic
```

How should I rectify this ?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu and is there a reason you want this kernel?

Comment: That is the HWE kernel for 20.04 as of 2/28/2022

Answer (score 0):

OK, so my previous answer didn't work for me: When building my module I got errors in the kernel source itself. Something was amiss.
Ended up following the [KernelGitGuide][1]
In my case was for the focal (20.04 LTS), and then switched to the branch for the tag that corresponds to my runtime kernel:

```
# git branch -vv
  master cacce8b48341 [origin/master] UBUNTU: Ubuntu-5.4.0-96.109
* temp   8d3dd3c45e92 UBUNTU: Ubuntu-hwe-5.13-5.13.0-30.33~20.04.1
```

After that make the link in the /usr/src:

```
:/usr/src# ls -ltr
total 28
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Feb 10 15:56 linux-headers-5.4.0-99
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Feb 10 15:56 linux-headers-5.4.0-99-generic
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Feb 18 06:27 linux-headers-5.4.0-100
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Feb 18 06:27 linux-headers-5.4.0-100-generic
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Feb 28 23:38 linux-hwe-5.13-headers-5.13.0-30
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Feb 28 23:42 linux-headers-5.13.0-30-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    6 Mar  1 00:20 linux -> focal/
drwxr-xr-x 28 root root 4096 Mar  1 00:20 focal
```

Where "focal" dir is where the git repo was cloned.
[1]: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Dev/KernelGitGuide